# FileNotFound error in Java compress

Tags: java, file, io, zip, inputstream

I am trying to zip files using Java. My requirement is to zip anything, which means,

1. Folder
2. Folders
3. File
4. Files
5. Folders with Sub folders
6. Files (which are not in the folder) and folders

You can see the above requirement pretty well in almost every compress program including winzip.

Below is what I have tried.

**Compress.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Compress
{

    private List<String> fileList;
    private static final String SOURCE_FOLDER = ExpressWizard.filePath.getPath();
    private static final String OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE = ExpressWizard.destination.getPath();

    public Compress()
    {
        fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(SOURCE_FOLDER + "\n");
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);

    }

    public Compress(File[] list)
    {
        fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(SOURCE_FOLDER + "\n");
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);

    }



    public void zipIt(String zipFile, File[] list)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String source = "";
        ZipOutputStream zos=null;


        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                String SOURCE_FOLDER = list[i].getPath();

                try
                {
                    source = SOURCE_FOLDER.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, SOURCE_FOLDER.length());
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    source = SOURCE_FOLDER;
                }


                System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + zipFile);
                FileInputStream in = null;

                for (String file : this.fileList)
                {
                    System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
                    ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);
                    zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                    try
                    {
                        in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file);
                        int len;
                        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                        {
                            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    } finally
                    {
                        in.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            System.out.println("Folder successfully compressed");

        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                zos.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void generateFileList(File node)
    {

        // add file only
        if (node.isFile())
        {
            System.out.println("File executed");
            fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.toString()));

        }

        if (node.isDirectory())
        {
            System.out.println("Folder executed");
            String[] subNote = node.list();
            for (String filename : subNote)
            {
                generateFileList(new File(node, filename));
            }
        }
    }

    public void generateFileList(File[] node)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < node.length; i++)
        {
            // add file only
            if (node[i].isFile())
            {
                System.out.println("File executed");
                fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.toString()));

            }

            if (node[i].isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println("Folder executed");
                String[] subNote = node[i].list();
                for (String filename : subNote)
                {
                    generateFileList(new File(node[i], filename));
                }
            }
        }

    } 

    private String generateZipEntry(String file)
    {
        return file.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.length() + 1, file.length());
    }

}
```

This is how we call the above class.

**ExpressWizard.java**

```
private void backUpButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
    {                                                 
        try
        {
            Compress compress = new Compress();
            if (CompressType.ZIP==zip)
            {    
                compress.generateFileList(serlectFiles);
                System.out.println(destination.getPath());
                compress.zipIt(destination.getPath(),serlectFiles);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error in creating a zip compression ! ");
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

This code generated the below error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\Desktop\contact\drivingLicense.png (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.compression.Compress.zipIt(Compress.java:138)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.view.ExpressWizard.backUpButtonActionPerformed(ExpressWizard.java:2781)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.view.ExpressWizard.access$5900(ExpressWizard.java:31)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.view.ExpressWizard$40.actionPerformed(ExpressWizard.java:2021)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.view.HomePanel.clickPanel01MouseClicked(HomePanel.java:653)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.view.HomePanel.access$000(HomePanel.java:16)
    at com.theace.backupsystem.view.HomePanel$1.mouseClicked(HomePanel.java:120)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The error is basically happening when we select more than one folder. And the error is true, it says the `drivingLicense.png` is not in `C:\Users\user\Desktop\contact\` path. Yes that is right, it in `C:\Users\user\Desktop\screens\` which is the other folder I selected.

It seems like the above code is messing up with the paths, how can I fix it?

Apart from that, how can we arrange this code to compress files, folders etc which I described as "requirements" ?

Comment: You shouldn't extract parent folders by looking for the last backslash in the filename, but call `File.getParentFile()` instead and in general use `File` over `String` for files.

Comment: @Axel: Any better explanation pls?

Comment: You try to do something that the `File` class already does for you, and you can safely assume that that code is thoroughly tested including all the corner cases. That should be enough IMHO. But I think I spotted something else in your code. Just a moment...

Comment: @Axel: The paths are still mixed up..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you "forget" the directory name for subfolders:

```
private String generateZipEntry(String file)
{
    return file.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.length() + 1, file.length());
}
```

This will always create an entry for a file in the directory `SOURCE_FOLDER`. But you call `generateFileList()` recursively:

```
        if (node[i].isDirectory())
        {
            System.out.println("Folder executed");
            String[] subNote = node[i].list();
            for (String filename : subNote)
            {
                // here, you pass a subdirectory, but in
                // generateZipEntry() you always append
                // filename to SOURCE_FOLDER, and not the
                // directoy the file is in
                generateFileList(new File(node[i], filename));
            }
        }
```

You should pass directoy and filename (or better a `File` object) to `generateZipEntry`.

Comment: Not now, still busy in office... Probably something like changing `generateZipEntry(String file)` to `generateZipEntry(File file)` and `return file.getPath.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.length() + 1);` should work.

Comment: OK Thanks. Look forward for your response.

Comment: I've done the changes which were you mentioned above . But until to now I couldn't full fill my requirement  . Help me to full fill it .